# Enable resizing Windows Forms forms

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

How can I resize my forms by clicking their border? I even set `FormBorderStyle` to `sizable`. What am I missing?

Here are the properties of the form:

[image: Properties1]

[image]

**Designer.cs Form part:**

```
        //
        // Form1
        //
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(750, 378);
        this.Controls.Add(this.rtxt_inactiveprograms);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lbl_time);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lsv_runningapps);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btn_start);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lst_runningprocess);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txt_pcname);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btn_ping);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Okay, I'll just update it. Hang on.

Comment: Check what value your have given to form1.MaximizeBox and form1.MinimizeBox these value should be set to false.

Comment: @Dnyanesh By false meaning `0,0` right?

Comment: @GrantWinney I have on my Form1_load `this.Location = new Point(0, 0);` and `this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;`. Should I remove it?

Comment: @GrantWinney even the lower-right corner won't work. Oh, by the way I'm using `XP` and `VS2010` if thats got to do with anything.

Comment: @GrantWinney I tried creating a new project with a blank form and I can resized it from all corners.

Comment: @GrantWinney I got it, turns out I only need to change my `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowOnly`

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah I'm good for now. Thanks.

Comment: My bad sorry. Meant to put form1.MaximizeBox and form1.MinimizeBox  set to true. Because this stop working of minimize and maximize button. Was just suggesting for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizebox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GrantWinney I think its not that really helpful since when creating a project `AutoSizeMode` is always set to `GrowOnly` as default I think. But I'll post my solution anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resizing issues here are that you just need to change `AutoSizeMode` from `GrowAndShrink` to `GrowOnly`.

But resizing here doesn't affect the contents of the form and doesn't adjust to you the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Set `FormBorderStyle` to `Sizable`.